# -bash cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a compute engine in google cloud and i am using it for a while

But for someday, I am getting the "**-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device**" while pressing the tab in keyboard for auto file/folder selection. I have done some research on this, and found out that the space in the root file execute this error. But the server is showing free spaces with command **df -h**

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmtS6.png)

Is there anyone having the issue?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the root file system has 48 GB of free space. Edit your question to show the command that you are using. You might be trying to store data on a read-only file system.

Comment: @JohnHanley i am using the command **df -h** and i have provided the write access to tmp as well.

Comment: The command that caused the error message and not the command to list free space. Also, do not include links to images in your question. Copy and paste the text into your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have upated the image with the command that i have used. and the error message appeares when pressing tab from keyboard to auto select file/folder

Comment: What does **df -i** show? Maybe you have run out of free i-nodes.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you so much for the help. My i-nodes were full, that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A resolution to this issue would be to resize the persistent disk [guide to resize](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/working-with-persistent-disks#resize_pd), keep in mind to backup [guide to snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) the disk, by creating a snapshot, in order to protect it against any unforeseen circumstances that may appear, especially if you have no recoverable files on the disk.

Also, another option would be to add another disk to the VM [guide to add disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk?hl=en).

If the resizing process finishes successfully, it is advised to restart the machine and get the existing files out, because even if the workaround is feasible.